# Failed to compile. Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

After `npm start`, the browser gives the error:

> Failed to compile ./src/components/App/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'.

React-router-dom has been added to the dependencies in npm and so has react-router and react.

Project has been created using the `create-react-app myapp` cmd line. This is runned on a localhost, node server. I have an api and app folder inside my project folder. I have tried various things. Updated manually my package.json inside the app folder, reinstalled react-router-dom, delete the package-lock.json in the app folder and reinitialize it. My api folder holds nothing but node_modules, my api file, route.js, config.js, index.js and also a package.json and package-lock.json. I have tried the npm build command in my app folder. It just creates a 'build' folder which holds the same files as my public folder inside my app folder. I also tried running `yarn add react-router-dom`.

```
//=========App.js file=========

//dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

//components
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';
import Home from '../Pages/Home';
import StudentOverview from '../Pages/StudentOverview';
import StudentDetails from '../Pages/StudentDetails';
import Management from '../Pages/Management';
import StudentAdd from '../Pages/StudentAdd';
import Exercise from '../Exercise/Exercise';

//includes
import '../../../public/css/kdg-fonts.css';
import '../../../public/css/normalize.css';
import '../../../public/css/responsive.css';
import '../../../public/css/say-my-name.css';
import '../../../public/css/style.css';

//Run
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path='*' component={Header} />
          <Route path='*' component={Footer} />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route exact path='/studenten' component={StudentOverview} />
          <Route exact path='/studenten/:id' component={StudentDetails} />
          <Route exact path='/beheer' component={Management} />
          <Route exact path='/beheer/add' component={StudentAdd} />
          <Route exact path='/oefenen' component={Exercise} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

//=========appfolder/package.json file=========

{
  "name": "saymyname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-changed": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity can you try creating your app using npx to execute the latest version of create-react-app?  e.g. `npx create-react-app myapp`.  I'm wondering if you have an older version of CRA

Comment: @DMcCallum83 Before I made my project I have installed the latest version of create-react-app. To answer your question, I have used `npx create-react-app myapp` and this worked properly.

Comment: In my case, I was getting the error because I was importing components from react-router-dom in both app.js and index.js and was not using one of them. removing the imports which I wasn't using solved the issue.

Answer (score 163):

The following command will resolve it:

```
npm install react-router-dom --save
```

You can use `-S` (capitalized) instead of `--save` if you want; [they both do the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54471399/what-npm-install-s-mean/54471513#54471513).

Answer (score 62):

In my case I use Typescript and I needed to install

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

AND

```
npm i @types/react-router-dom
```

Would also recommend closing and restarting your IDE after installing both

After restarting, both installations errors are gone.

Answer (score 13):

This error will be fixed by following these steps:

1. `npm install --save react-router-dom`
2. Put this in `public/index.js`:

   ```
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: It works when done only Step.1. No need do the Step.2

Answer (score 5):

Just install react-router-dom by using:

```
yarn add react-router-dom
```

---

<sup>or `npm install --save react-router-dom` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59137702/6045800).</sup>

Answer (score 4):

> For this problem "Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'
> in"

```
//I found the following solving

// using ES6 modules

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

if it is not working so you have to use the following that I used using CommonJS modules

```
const BrowserRouter = require("react-router-dom").BrowserRouter;

const Route = require("react-router-dom").Route;

const Link = require("react-router-dom").Link;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command.

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

If not working.

```
npm i react-router-dom --save
```

Or.

```
npm i react-router-dom --force
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using yarn instead of npm, this will help:

```
yarn add react-router-dom --save
```

Comment: yarn add react-router-dom --save
Unknown Syntax Error: Command not found; did you mean one of:

  0. yarn add [--json] [-E,--exact] [-T,--tilde] [-C,--caret] [-D,--dev] [-P,--peer] [-O,--optional] [--prefer-dev] [-i,--interactive] [--cached] [--mode #0] ...
  1. yarn add [--json] [-E,--exact] [-T,--tilde] [-C,--caret] [-D,--dev] [-P,--peer] [-O,--optional] [--prefer-dev] [-i,--interactive] [--cached] [--mode #0] ...

While running add react-router-dom --save

Answer (score 1):

To install and configure react router. You first need to install the react-router-dom. Type the below command and run in your terminal,

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

If you are using react-router-dom v6. Then use the below code to configure react-router-dom along with layout,

App.jsx:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Components/Home'
import About from './Components/About'
import Layout from './Components/Layout'


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After configuring the react router in App.jsx. I am creating 3 components Home, About and Layout. Home and About are regular components and Layout component is to handle the Layout part in react-router-dom using `Outlet`.

Layout.jsx

```
import { Outlet, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <>

            <Link to="/">Home</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            <Outlet />
        </>
    )
}
```

Home.jsx

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <p>This is Home</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

About.jsx

```
export default function About() {
    return (
        <>
            <p>This is About Us</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have already installed the dependencies, checked the package.Json file for the react-router-dom dependency to be sure and it still doesn't work...
In this case, make sure you import the packages from 'react-router-dom' in the index.js file:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue when Docker and yarn involved with the error.

The key was to rebuild the Docker image after setting react-router-dom as the dev dependency, just like many answers here detail. **The `node_modules` folder inside docker container needs to update!** If your `docker-compose.yaml` parameter file does not remount `node_modules` as a volume or otherwise update it, then this answer will not work for your project. Steps:

1. `docker-compose down` in project root, or stop the daemon in Docker Desktop
2. `yarn remove react-router-dom`
3. `yarn add --dev react-router-dom` adds react-router-dom as dev dependency
4. `docker-compose build` to rebuild the Docker image
5. `docker-compose up -d` for starting the devserver with daemon

In my case I was using Docker, with `create-react-app` using Typescript template.
I'm using `docker-compose` to up and down the containers with Docker daemon. If you don't use `docker-compose` then you need to modify the container start/stop commands accordingly.

React Router was already installed and functioning correctly (`yarn start` outside Docker container was not reporting any error). Docker contained frontend server was not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
```

These are the dependencies you use in your project, make sure to install `react-router-dom` in to your react project.

Use
`npm i react-router-dom` or `yarn add react-router-dom` to install react-router-dom in to your project.

If you use typescript in your project, you have to install `@types/react-router-dom` too

Use `npm i @types/react-router-dom` or `yarn add @types/react-router-dom` to install them.

Finally if you have successfully installed those libs in to your project, your **package.json** can be look like this,

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
     ......
    "react-router-dom": "^x.x.x",
     .....
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^x.x.x",
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `--save` while installing "react-router-dom". This will ensure that package is stored in `package.json` file as a dependency and when you try to build the solution on any another machine or on build server, it will take all the dependencies from `package.json` file and install them.

If you want to install all dependencies on a fresh machine, run the command - `npm install`