# What npm install -s mean?

Tags: npm-install

I am installing some packages on NPM, sometimes I have to write -s and -g? What do they mean?

```
npm install -s socket.io
npm install -g xxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 14):

`npm -g <package>` will install a package globally on your machine. Without the `-g` or `--global` flag, the package will be installed locally in the directory you were in when you ran the command.

`npm -S <package>` with an *uppercase* `-S` or `--save` will install the package and save it to your dependencies in your `package.json`, although I believe that is now the default behavior in current npm. I recommend [reading the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) if you're unfamiliar with what's happening when you pass different options to npm.

Comment: Unfortunately the docs don't actually say what `-s` does, so this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 10):

[@gmmetheny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8304911/gpmetheny) answered the question about the global `-g` flag, but `-s` appears to *silence* the output of the command (at least in npm v7.0.15).

In other words, including `-s` (or `--silent`) in your `npm install` command means that it will have no output (only a newline):

```
> npm install -s example-package1 example-package2
```

This may be useful for running the command in a script.

Running the command *without* the `-s` flag echoes information about what was installed, e.g.:

```
> npm install example-package1 example-package2

npm WARN deprecated some-pkg@1.2.3: this library is no longer supported

added 160 packages, and audited 160 packages in 6s

14 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

You can diff the resulting directories created after running each variant of the command and you can verify that the effects are the same.

As [@Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341772/max) mentioned, this option is NOT mentioned in the `npm` docs (at least not in any prevalent location where a user might find it after a reasonable amount of searching).

Answer (score 1):

npm install -g  will install a package globally on your machine, means it will be available for all other user in computer. Without the -g or --global flag, the package will be installed locally in the directory you are currently working in, and will be available to you only.

npm install -s  this will install package and also make and entry in package.json file. -s stands for --save. without -s, npm will install the package but will not make any entry in package.json.

Comment: What you're referring to is `-S` and not `-s`, the former is the shorthand for `--save` and the latter is the shorthand for `--silent`.